# Getting the Google Identification Number

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-admin-sdk

For users in a Google domain, there's a property called `gidNumber`. The only way I know of how I can access this id is by connecting to the Google Ldap. When I do a query in Google Admin Directory, I cannot find this property. Are there other methods to accessing the `gidNumber` other than via ldap?

Comment: I think you are talking about the unique user `id`, or the group id `gid` on the user object. https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users also https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users

Comment: @wp78de I need an id that will not change if the user changes their name. Something that is globally unique across Google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ID that you can use to identify any user, the first one is the email address ( that could be changed but Google API's use to recognise a userKey ) and then is the ID for a user, which can be get if you run the [Admin SDK](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/get) using as Userkey from a user that you know the email address.

Comment: Is there documentation somewhere stating that the ID of a user will not change despite any/all of their fields being updated? That it is immutable?

Comment: If you read the information for the property "id"  on the follow [link](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users#resource) you will see that this is an unique ID to identify the user, however,. I have not found more documentation referring this field  but after testing it in some scenarios (name changed, email address (including the domain) changed and deleting the user),  that ID continues been the same.